# Trying to install programming environment on OS X Yosemite - bash: sudo: command not found

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I am trying to install a Java programming environment for a Coursera Algorithims class I am taking and am getting an error on OS X that I am not sure how to troubleshoot.

Trying to install the environment with the instructions detailed here:
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/mac/

When I lick on the icon and it launches it errors out with:

```
Last login: Sun Jul 19 15:26:34 on ttys001
Timothys-MacBook-Pro:~ TimBram$ echo

Timothys-MacBook-Pro:~ TimBram$ bash
clear;echo -e "Launching the automatic installer algs4.app...

Please enter your user password to begin installation.
Note: You won't see the characters as you type them.
";sudo bash '/Users/TimBram/Downloads/algs4.app/Contents/Resources/launcher.sh' ${USER};exit &> /dev/null
bash-3.2$ clear;echo -e "Launching the automatic installer algs4.app...
> 
> Please enter your user password to begin installation.
> Note: You won't see the characters as you type them.
> ";sudo bash '/Users/TimBram/Downloads/algs4.app/Contents/Resources/launcher.sh' ${USER};exit &> /dev/null
bash: clear: command not found
Launching the automatic installer algs4.app...

Please enter your user password to begin installation.
Note: You won't see the characters as you type them.

bash: sudo: command not found
Timothys-MacBook-Pro:~ TimBram$
```

I am not sure where to go from here because I definitely have the bash terminal on my Mac and sudo works fine for me and is definitely found.  I have searched for similar error with Google and in the class forum but can't see anyone else having a similar issue.

Comment: I suspect your PATH environment variable is set incorrectly. Try `echo $PATH` and see if it contains `/bin`, `/usr/bin` at least. If not, you will need to edit your profile, probably in `$HOME/.profile` and set it in there.

Comment: Hum...no, it looks like it is in there.  Strange.

Timothys-MacBook-Pro:~ TimBram$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/TimBram/anaconda/bin:/Users/TimBram/Documents/Anaconda2/anaconda/bin:/Users/TimBram/Documents/Anaconda/anaconda/bin:/Users/TimBram/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin